# check if ajax request is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, geocoding, mapquest

I use the free geocoding API of mapquest

**I want to check if the request is sucessfull, but returned no data.**

I type "vdfsbvdf54vdfd" (just a silly string) as adress in a form field. 
I expect an alert like so "Sorry, wrong input". Alert never happens.

This is my code snippet

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "`http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=012`",
     data: { location: ad, maxResults: 1}
     })


 .done(function( response ) {alert(response);
         var geoclng = response.results[0].locations[0].latLng.lng;
        var geoclat = response.results[0].locations[0].latLng.lat;

        if (geoclng=="") {alert("Sorry, wrong input");}

         //now use lon/lat on map etc
                          )}
```

I tried `if (geoclng=="") {alert("Sorry, wrong input");}`

also `if (response.length=0) {alert("Sorry, wrong input");}`

and also `if ($.isEmptyObject(response)) {alert("Sorry, wrong input");}`

and alert never happens.

If it helps, when I alert the response I get `object Object`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the extra single quotes around the url and check for the length of the locations array:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=012",
    data: { location: ad, maxResults: 1}
     })
 .done(function( response ) {
     alert(response.results[0].locations.length); //if greater than zero, you have results
     if( response.results[0].locations.length > 0 ){
         var geoclng = response.results[0].locations[0].latLng.lng;
         var geoclat = response.results[0].locations[0].latLng.lat;
         //now use lon/lat on map etc
     } else {
         alert("Sorry, wrong input");
     }
  )}
```

When you run a call to http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=012, it is going to return an object whether or not there were matches. The contents of that object's locations array will be empty is nothing was found.

`response.length == 0` or `response == ""` will evaluate to `false` since there is always a response returned.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details, By the way the extra single quotes on the URL was to mark it as code. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to check the success/failed request.

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.get("example.php", function() {
    alert("success");
})
.done(function() {
    alert("second success");
})
.fail(function() {
    alert("error");
})
.always(function() {
    alert("finished");
});
// Perform other work here ...
// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.always(function() {
    alert("second finished");
});
```

for more detail read more on this link https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Thanks, but I already have this structure of code. I have the `.done` and `.fail`. I ment that a request is successfull and returns empty data, so has to do with the `.done` part.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this one in your ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=012",
  data: { 
     location: ad, maxResults: 1
  }
})
```

Add this one (just under the `data` parameter)

```
success: function (response) {
  if (response == '') {
    alert('Sorry!');
  }
}
```

This will run on the success event, and will check for the response returned from the server. Then an if else block to test its value.

I would like to forward you to learn more about jQuery Ajax API: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/